# All input forms in MaterializeCSS in electron look smashed

Tags: javascript, html, css, electron, materialize

Okay, so when I follow the directions [here](http://materializecss.com/getting-started.html) for getting started with Materialize CSS, my input form always turns out like this:

[image: the weirrd error]
My current `index.html` file is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>IRS</title>

    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--Import materialize.css-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/materialize-css/css/ghpages-materialize.css">

    <!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/materialize-css/js/materialize.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="input-field">
      <input placeholder="Placeholder" id="first_name" type="text" class="validate">
      <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

My electron version is 1.6.6 and node is at 6.10.3

Comment: add class "active" to the <label></label> and try... hope it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add "active" class to the  tag and try

```
 <div class="input-field">
          <input placeholder="Placeholder" id="first_name" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="first_name" class="active">First Name</label>
        </div>
```

if you want only label animation, remove the placeholder for the `<input>` tag

Hope it works..

Comment: Well, it's no longer smashed together, but there's no animation. It answers my question and I found a different library to work with, so thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else with issues using materialize css with electron, here is how to get it to work the right way:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/hammer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

The issue is materialize.min.js is requiring hammer.min.js so you need to add it to your project and call it before materilize.min.js